# edit strings in a dictionary to remove occurrence of two specific characters

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I am running a python-BeautifulSoup code to obtain commodity price data from a website. The problem I am facing is that the output includes unnecessary "\n" and white space, the former which I am unable to edit out.

I was able to remove the white space using the `.replace` function, however it didn't work for the "\n".

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import html5lib


URL= "https://tradingeconomics.com/commodities"
response=requests.get(URL)


soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html5lib')
print(soup)



C1=soup.find(class_='table table-hover table-striped').find('tbody')
C2=C1.find_all('tr')

for tr in C2:
    td=tr.find_all('td')
    row=[i.text for i in td]
    row=str(row)
    row=row.replace(' ','').replace("\n",'')
    print(row)
```

This is the output I am currently getting:
`['\n\n','\n\nUranium\n\n\n','\n\n24.0500\n','\n\n0.20\n','\n0.84%\n','\n-0.21%\n','\n-5.32%\n','\n-16.35%\n','\nNov/01\n']`

This is the output I want which excludes the `\n`:
`['','Uranium','24.0500','0.20','0.84%','-0.21%','-5.32%','-16.35%','Nov/01']`

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just do `.strip()`. Strip without parameters strips all whitespace - spaces, newlines (`\n`). ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.strip()` on your string directly. It removes **leading + trailing** whitespaces and new line characters by default. More examples [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/strip.html#example-1).

Example:

```py
your_string = '\n\nUranium\n\n\n'

print(your_string.strip())
```

Outputs:

```
Uranium
```

---

The issue is here:

```
row=[i.text for i in td] #['\n\n', '\nUranium\n' ....]
row=str(row)
```

You are trying to convert a list of strings to a single string. Which is why you were not getting the output you're expecting. You should update each string in list.

Try this:

```py
for tr in C2:
    td=tr.find_all('td')
    row=[i.text.strip() for i in td]
    print(row)
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `strip()` only removes leading and trailing characters

Comment: @DashWinterson, good spot. Updated the answer to include it. :)

Comment: Hi guys, it didnt work for strange reasons. i tried  also to.replace  '\n' with  ' ' but also didnt work. can you try running the code and please advise?